# Function inside tinymce addcommand

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

is it possible to create a function inside the addcommand area of a tinymce custom button on wordpress visual editor?

```
ed.addCommand("green_command", function() {
            if (jQuery(".shortcode-container").css("display") == "block")
            {
                jQuery(".shortcode-container").css("display","none")
            }
            else if(jQuery(".shortcode-container").css("display") == "none")
            {
                jQuery(".shortcode-container").css("display","block")
            }
            else
            {
                jQuery(".mce-toolbar-grp").append("<div style=\" border: 3px solid rgb(132, 43, 43) \" class=\" shortcode-container \"><table style=\"background: rgb(84, 86, 87); padding: 10px;\" class=\"the_projects\">  </table></div>"); 
                // var selected_text = ed.selection.getContent();
                 var return_text = "";
                // ed.execCommand("mceInsertContent", 0, return_text);
                //
                var t = {action: "GET_ALL_BOXES", data: {}};
                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, t, function(t) 
                {
                    //var thediv = "<table style=\"width: 100px; height: 100px; background: black;\" class=\"the_projects\">  </table>";
                    jQuery(".the_projects").html("");
                    jQuery.each(t, function(t, n) 
                    {
                      var r = n.box.replace(/\\/g, "");
                      var id = n.id;
                      var name = n.name;
                      var shortcode = n.short_code.replace("test",n.id);
                      jQuery(".the_projects").append('<span value="' + shortcode + '" class="button_code button" style="margin:0px 10px">' + name + '</span>' );   
                    });
                //jQuery(".the_projects").css("display","block");
                })

            }

           jQuery(".button_code").click(function(){

            alert("yes");

           })

        });
```

As you can see when the button is clicked, it dynanmically creates a div with several elements inside, including a button. What I want is when the dynamically created button is clicked, I want to alert it's value. But it's not working somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to end appropriate lines with `;` - quite a few are missing which is likely the cause of this not working.

Restructuring the code as

```
$('<span value="' + shortcode + '" class="button_code button" style="margin:0px 10px">' + name + '</span>')
.appendTo(".the_projects")
.click(function(){
    alert("yes");
});
```

is also a good idea, making

```
jQuery(".button_code").click(function(){
  alert("yes");
})
```

redundant.